# Ajax response in not working properly in laravel 7

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I am doing a simple insert in laravel 7 using ajax, here the validation is working properly but the success result is not working or showing propoerly.

The routes are

```
// Product Poutes
Route::get('create/product', 'Product\ProductController@create')->name('createProduct');
Route::post('store/product', 'Product\ProductController@store')->name('storeProduct');
```

The Model is

```
<?php

namespace App\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'category_id','sell_price','purchase_price',
    ];
}
```

The Controller code

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        
        $validation = Validator::make(
            $request->all(),
            [
                'name' => 'required|unique:products|max:120|min:4',
                'category_id' => 'required',
                'sell_price' => 'required',
                'purchase_price' => 'required'
            ]
        );

        if ($validation) {
            return response()->json(['error' => $validation->errors()->all()]);
        }

        $product = new Product;
        $product->name = $request->name;
        $product->category_id = $request->category_id;
        $product->sell_price = $request->sell_price;
        $product->purchase_price = $request->purchase_price;

        $product->save();

        return response()->json(['success' => "New Product Added!"]);
    }
```

The Blade form

```
@extends('layouts.newApp')

<!-- Product create -->
@section('content')
    <!-- Begin Page Content -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Page Heading -->
        <h1 class="h3 mb-4 text-gray-800">Create Product</h1>
        <div class="row">
            <form method="POST">
                @csrf
                <div class="row justify-content-center">
                    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                        <div id="div-error" class="col-md-10 justify-content-center">
                            <div class="alert alert-danger print-error-msg" style="display:none">
                                <ul></ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                        <label for="category">Category</label>
                        <select id="category_id" class="form-control custom-select" name='category_id'>
                            <option selected>Choose...</option>
                            @foreach ($categories as $category)
                                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Product Name" name='name'>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="sell_price">Notes</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sell_price" placeholder="sell_price"
                            name='sell_price'>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-5">
                        <label for="purchase_price">Notes</label>
                        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="purchase_price" placeholder="purchase_price"
                            name='purchase_price'>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group col-md-10">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $(".btn-submit").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': jQuery('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

                var category_id = document.getElementById("category_id").value;
                var name = $("input[name=name]").val();
                var sell_price = $("input[name=sell_price]").val();
                var purchase_price = $("input[name=purchase_price]").val();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: "{{ route('storeProduct') }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        category_id: category_id,
                        name: name,
                        sell_price: sell_price,
                        purchase_price: purchase_price
                    },

                    success: function(data) {
                        if ($.isEmptyObject(data.error)) {
                            alert(data.success);
                        } else {
                            printErrorMsg(data.error);
                        }
                    }
                });
            });

            function printErrorMsg(msg) {
                $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").html('');
                $(".print-error-msg").css('display', 'block');
                $.each(msg, function(key, value) {
                    $(".print-error-msg").find("ul").append('<li>' + value + '</li>');
                });
            }

        });

    </script>

@endsection
```

The validation is working fine:

[image]

But after I add data and press submit it returns undefined type:

[image]

I tried all sort of possible method found non.
Hope to sort out the problem very soon.

Comment: Have you tried to `console.log(data)` in your `success` handler to see what you actually get? My bet is it's a JSON encoded string which you first need to parse before using it as an object.

Comment: @El_Vanja jQuery does the parsing automatically.

Comment: This is the message show by the console log.
TypeError: 'caller', 'callee', and 'arguments' properties may not be accessed on strict mode functions or the arguments objects for calls to them
    at Function.o (<anonymous>:1:83)

Answer (score 0):

may be you are getting some error in your response.why dont you check your ajax hit in inspect element to see what its returning i think its returning some php error or something else or you data in json maybe